# How do I get the quest from the brown aliens of Silence?

Tags: galaxy-trucker

I'm playing the campaign in the game Galaxy Trucker on Android and I've arrived at the planet Silence, home of the brown aliens. The game tells me that there is a quest available if I speak to the natives, but I cannot get them to give it to me. All of the conversation options end with me telling them to talk to me and them ending the conversation in a huff.

How do I get the quest on this planet?

[image: Silence, home of the brown aliens.]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure why the previous submission from Bob has a down rating. He's exactly right, unfortunately my rep is too low to comment, so I'll add this as a separate answer instead.

To get access to the Brown Aliens follow the following:

1. Talk to the aliens, they will not respond usefully to anything you say.
2. Talk to the Business man, tell him you're having trouble communicating with aliens.
3. He'll offer to help after his next meeting.
4. Talk to the aliens again. Look for the  ... message you can now use.
5. If it's not there, run through the conversation again, the business man will pop up at the end, explaining his meeting ran long, and telling you what to say.
6. Go back to the brown aliens the ... option will be there this time.

Comment: It may have been due to his poor formatting and comparing with your answer, it (the one below by 'bob') is kinda a bit confusing.

Answer (score -1):

talk to the business man he will give you an answer (your character will say "...") if you had worked for him.